# How to configure "-incognito" for default apps on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I can update any shortcut for Chrome with "-incognito" so browsing would be safer (without ex.: poisoned history).

**Q:** But: If I click on a link in an ex.: DOC, then chrome opens as normal, not incognito.

Tried to search for registry edits, how to add "-incognito" to default applications like chrome, but still the same issue.

Comment: What exactly do you consider to be a “default application”.   Google Chrome currently isn’t installed by default on any version of Windows.  Edge Chromium isn’t (should not) considered to be Google Chrome.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: File association is located in the HK_CR. It starts listing extensions. From those, you have to either edit the extension (such as .html) or if they have an OpenWithProgsId, see what the ID is, which in this case is ChromeHTML. Then scroll down to ChromeHTML, and make the changes there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing this registry option works for me when chrome is set to the default browser

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command]
From: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"
To: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito -- "%1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command] From: "C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1" To:
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
> --incognito -- "%1"
```

That doesnt exist in the latest version of W10.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).